# Supremum vs Integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Let $h$ be a positive function defined on $(0,\infty)$. Is the following inequality always true ?
$$
\sup_{r<t<\infty}h(t)\leq\int_{r}^{\infty}h(t)\frac{dt}{t}
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $h(t) = \dfrac{1}{t^2}$, we have $\displaystyle\sup_{r < t < \infty}h(t) = \dfrac{1}{r^2}$ but $\displaystyle\int_{r}^{\infty}h(t)\dfrac{dt}{t} = \dfrac{1}{2r^2}$.